# Jspdf how to add auto popup printbox when pdf file is download

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I am trying to creating pdf while clicking on form, and its working fine, but client wants to add an option that when pdf file opened, print out box will also open, is there any parameter in JSPDF function, which can resolve this issue...

here is some of the code:

```
var createPDF = function() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLCgoLDhgQDg0NDh0VFhEYIx8lJCIfIiEmKzcvJik0KSEiMEExNDk7Pj4+JS5ESUM8SDc9Pjv/2wBDAQoLCw4NDhwQEBw7KCIoOzs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozv/wAARCACeAXQDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAGwABAAIDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEGAwQFAgf/xABAEAABBAEBBQQGBQwCAwEAAAABAAIDBAURBhIhMUETMlFhFCJxgZGxFSNCodEHMzVDUlNVYnJzksEkYxY0k+H/xAAZAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAX/xAAnEQEAAgEDBAICAgMAAAAAAAAAAQIRAxIxBBMhUUHwFKFhcSKB8f/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A+zIiICIiAiIgIoRBKKEQSihEEooRBKKEQSihEEooRBKKEQSihEEooRBKKEQSihEEooRBKKF4mnjrxOlleGMaNXOPIIMiLlf+TYT+JQf5Leq24LsImrStljPJzeSDOihEEooRBKKEQSiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIoQEREBERARE1CAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgLmbRfoG5/aK6a5u0P6Ct/2yg+MGueei+sbDDTZuEeBK+eCv6o4dF9F2LGmz8Y8HFUd9ERQEREBERBKIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICKCtXIZGvjKrrFl+60dOpPgEGy54aCXEADqVxMjtjhscS2Sz2jx9mIbypec2jyGYe5jXOgrdI2nifaVwTU6lXAvEn5TKAcRHSmcPEkBZa/5SMXI4CaCeLz0BVB9GagqtKYH17H57G5Mf8W0x5/ZJ0PwXR11XxOOB8Tw+NzmOHItOhCt+z+2E9Zza2UcZIjwE3Vvt8UwL6i8RyNlja9jg5rhqCOq9qCVBRcrN52vhq+9J68ru5GOZQdKSeOFhfK9rGjmXHRcC7t1g6Ti3t3TOHSJuv3qiZbKZDMyl1mZwZ9mJp0aFzDUA58FcC+H8pmMDuFOwR7lt1fyiYSdwbIZoCer2cPuXzf0dniFIrNdy0KD7PTyVS/H2lWwyVv8AK7VbOq+LVfSaMwmqzPhkHItOivuzm1/pjm08jpHYPBsnIP8AwKgtqKAdUQSihauQyEGOrmaY+TWjm4+AQbJeGjUnQDqVzLW0mLqOLHT9o8fZjG8fuVfu2b2VcTO4xQdIGHT4nqsIpsjbo1oaPJUdo7ZUtfVq2iPHcA/2skW1+MedJBPD5vj4fcq8ewadDKwH2hemRRydxzXewoLpWvVrjN+vMyQfylamf44O3/bKqwpmKQSwPdDKOT2HQ/8A6tyznJHYmepkABI5mjJWjg/2+BQV5tbWMcOiueyPq4Ro8HuXBjrfVN4dArBsuNMO4eEjkkZpdp8NDK6OS/G17DoQehW1RytLJNc6nO2YM4OLei+SZSt2mVtO0/Wu+a3MTmLOHoWKtQbskxH1n7IQfScjn8Zix/y7TGO/ZHE/Bc2lt1ib9+OnXExfIdAS3QL5rLDJPIZJnue93EucdSVv7OQCPaGmf+wIPryIiglERAREQEREBERAREQERQg8TSshhfLI4NYwaknoF88y12bNWzO/UQN4Qs8B4+0qz7TzOfHDQYeM51f/AEhcSaBsELnuHBoVgceKhLYsNr14zJK/k0dPM+StmN2LpwNbJf8A+TLz3eTB7uvvW/s/ihRpiaRo9InG88+Hg33LroNaLH1IW7sdWJg8AwLHZxGPttLZqUT9f5Bqt1FBTcrsYImumxhJA4mBx1+BKrjawcCN0gg6OaeYK+qqsbSYxsMzcjG3QEhs4H3OVGlsxlH0Z24+w4mCQ6RE/Zd4exXRUaWjvxEDgeYPgVasNcN3GRSv/OAbr/6hwKDJk70eOpvsyHujgPE9Avndv0jIWX2rR1kf06NHgFZ9oZHXckyqNTHA3ecP5jyXLmruaGtjbrJI4NYPMoObTxNjI2vR6zNSO+88mDzVvx2yGNpgPmi9Jm6vk4j3DkujisbHjKbYWcXc3u6uPit5QYWVK7G7rYI2jwDQtO7gMZfYWz04yT9po3XD3hdJEHzzM7MzYgmaMmarrxcR6zPb4hc30MPbw9oIX1KSNsrHMe0Oa4aEHqqXZxn0fkn1APqnDfh9nUe5UdXZfMSWojRtu1sQj1XH7bfFWIclRXMfQnivRgh0LtT5t6hXiNwfG17TqHDUKDxYnjrwPmkdoxg1JVbEc2Rn9OsAjX80w/Yb+K6WTBu3YMeO4frJfYOQ+Ky3NylUfM4d0cB4noEHGn1ZI2CGPtbD+6wfM+AW7W2bZJo/JSGd37tpLWD4c/etzE0DXiNibQ2ZvWefDy9yx5raGphovrSXzHuxN5lBtR4jHRt3W0YAP7YWCxs/jLA41WRu6Oj9Qj4Kmz/lAyzpCYKULGdA7UldHFbfCWRseTq9jrw7RnED2oNu3QsYo78jjYq/tkesz2+IXp1OKzDo5oexw+KsYdHZhBaWvjeOfMELj16/oGRNI/mZdXQ69PFqDAKu6wADgAtvZ0aY2Qf9r1vGrwWpghpSmHhM/wCaCiWK3aXLDtOcrvmsTqoY0uPBduKt2j5nafrXfNZ6VBs+YrwPbqwavcD10VR4wmyItMFnItcIzxbCDoSPNWmtiMfU3TBShjLeRDBqPetwDRSooiIglERAREQEREBERAREQFClQg4M8RtbQT6jUQxNaPfxWO/jJ5o2CAM1a8OIfroQOi2oZBFnrwP2mxkfArNdykdNkZML5TI8Ma2MakkoMAs5sD8zU+LlPpOc/dVPi5ehlptP0Rd/wH4p9LTfwi7/AID8UHn0nOfuqnxcnpOc/dVPi5evpab+EXf8B+Kn6Wm/hF3/AAH4oPHpOc/dVPi5Ybf0zcrSV5Iam7I0tPFy2Ppab+EXf8B+KfS838Iu/wCA/FBhr4+RlaNkujntaA4jqV7wTTDJer9Gzbw94BXv6Xm0/RF3/AfimIE0lm7YlrS1xK5u62QAE6BBp1oDZsW5yNd6cgewcF6hrA56uwjhGxz9PPkFsYmZscU7HDi2w/X4qWSA7RMP7UBA9xQdfRERBKhEQFxdoYR/xLA7zJgNfI8F2lyc+4eiwN6unZp8UGvZob9aRpbzaVvYKQy4Oq5x1PZgH3cF7lsM7F/Ad0rFs9+g6/sPzKDWhm1zd2T9gNYPhqlyT0vIUqp4tMm+4eIC0u07PL32nn2gP3Beq0oOfq6nm1wCCw2JhXrSSnkxpKpD8ZNkJXW7ALny+tx6DoFcMowyY2dreJLCufUyVc1YtGt7oQV76A/k+5QcBw7n3KyyZCJzCGBrXacDpyXHg2huxWH17NOGVzeRjO6XDxAKqN3Zl8tOWTGykljW78WvQdQt/PDs60docHQSB2vl1XKq5unNnY3yg1A2It+uG7qT015LqZ+aN+Cncx7XBwABB114qK2PStW6681r4E71GY/9z/mtEWNIxx6Lc2cOuMe7xlf80GpjKvaQSO05yv8Ams1SHstoWjT9SfmveGsBlR7eH51/zXqOUSbRM06QH5oOwpUIgIiIJREQEREBERAREQEREBQpUIK9mCamYgscmTsMZPmOI/2tTITPkrbzOL4nB7faDqu5maH0jj3wtOkjfWjd4OHJU+O44gtkBZIw7r2Hm0jmqi80rcdynFZiOrZGhwWdUjE5r6IsOZLqacrtTp+rJ6+xXOCeOxG2WF7ZGOGoc06gqKyKVCIGq0MplGY2FjjG6V8jt1kbTxKz3LsFGu6ezII2N6nqqVZyb8jeNuQFjQN2Fh+yPH2lB3DtPKGknFy6D/sb+K62Nu/SNGO0InRCTiGu56KmMMuQsx0Ye9KdHEfZb1KvMETIIWQxjRkbQ0DyCSK/O808vZhPASESt9/A/esM1z0e1XudInaP/pPArobSUnyV23IGkywcSBzLeqrfpTZY+erXBVF+a4PaHNIII1BClVPA51lQijbfpFyilPIeRVra4OGoOoPUKK9KFKjVAJVby9oWMtDXadWVvXf/AFHkFt5zPR46MwwkSWnj1WA93zKq8U3Zglz9+R53nuPUqjty2vqncehXT2cOuBrH+U/MqpyWvUdx6K17Ncdnqn9H+0kcbNA1c653Js8YI9oWjJbMM0NpvOB4cfZ1Vg2mx77mP7aFus1c77QOo6hU5tkSM16HmER9HiljsQNkYQ5kjdQfEFU3OY+3iZXz12OkqOO96vExn8F62dzzaDxRtv0ruP1Uh+wfA+SuTd2Ro5OaR7QVFfL/AKb/AJ1DbM+SnZHUY+SwD6hYOXt8l9Em2fxNh+/LQhc49d1bNejVps3a0DIm+DW6K5FJEsm86rfhDJ2d9h4g+Y8ljNWvqCzfY0HUsa4hp9y7e2DKbajZ3SBltp+p04l3lp4KtssEsBdwOnEIjozW+zhc7wCs+DgNbDQNcNHObvH38VUcVVflslHAATFGQ+U9NPBX7QBmg4ABJVUqVjcZK3XlK/5rbxcvabQDjyhPzXAZY3JZ268pXfNdPZqXtM84+EJ+aIuClQpUVCIiCUREBERAREQEREBERAREQQeSrO0mAknJv0G/XgfWR/vB+KsyEaoPlPpWurXAtcDo5rhoQfNZKmTt49+9SsOi15s5tPuV3zWytLL6y8YLHSVnX2jqqZe2TzdJxLIRaYOTojx+Co6cW3GSYNJKteQ+IcWrzNttk5GkRQV4fM6uKrElfIxOIfQtNP8AZcvcNHK2DpFjrLj/AGiPmiN2xfnuS9rbndM8cteQ9gSKWaxM2CvGZZX8Gtat7HbFZW24OtvZUj6jvP8AwV1xWCo4eLdrR+ue9I7i53vQa+z+EGKgMkxD7Uv5x3h5DyXZQckUVDhrwI1BVK2hwctCR9ymwuruOr2NHFh8R5K7KC0OBB0IPRB8pNkPbodCFt0c/kMcA2tY1jH6uQbwVlzGxda4501J/o0x4lunqH3dFVLmzOcpk61DM0faiO8qjtN26uhujqULj4h5H+lq2tr8paaWNdFWaefZjV3xKrzqmSadDQs6/wBpy2K+GzNpwEePnGvV7d0feg9tsAOc4uLnO4uc46kqXSWpKz54IyYoiN+Q8h5e1d/F7CSuIkyk4DefZRHn7Su5nMOZdnpKGOgY08N1o4BMiiOteoePRfQtmOOztP8Ao/2qKdkc+Rp6Mz/6K/4GpNRwtatOAJI2aOAOvFJV0CNRyVG2nwEtKV9+lGXQPOssbRxafEK8qHNDhoQCD0Kg+Rdu17eYIK3sftDkcWAyvOHxD9XKNQPYeisua2Jr3HOsUHitMeJbp6jvd0VSubPZqiT2lGSRo+3D6wVRYGbf2A3STHMJ8Wy6f6WC1tzkZ2ltevDX1+0SXkfJVVzbTTo6rO0+Bid+CywUsjZcGw0LLyfCMgfeg2ZbUtiYz2JnSynm5xWWlBZyVltaowveebujR4ldLGbD5G04PvyCtF1a06vP+grvjsVUxdcQ1IgwdXcy72lFY8NiIcRTEMfrPPF7zzcV0Hd0+xT0UO5KD5TYsbl2yNf1rvmu3sXJ2mck48oiufd2Szsl6eSKuwsfI5zT2nQldnY/AZPGZKSe7E1jXM3Ro7VUXNSoRQEREEoiICIiAiIgIiICIiAoUqEBFrWshUo7vpM7It46DePNLF+rVhbNPOxkbuTieBV2z6Zm9YzmeGymgWpLkqcFZtmSxG2F3deTwK0LmZiiyNBjLLOyn1167w6fetVpa3EMW1aV5n7LtaBNAscs0cEbpJXhjGjUkngFrtytB9Y2W2ozEDoX68AVmImeIbm9Y8TLc0RatbIVLcbpK9hkjW94g8lp3MvXkxtqWjZY+SFpPqnXQqxS0zjDM6tIjOXWRc2rkHuke2YxtZHE15fvceI46hZo8tQlgfOy1G6NnecDySa2j4I1KT8txFrVchUu73o07Jd06HdOuii3fq0WB1mdkW9wG8eam2c4w1vrjdnw2k0XHx+Yi9Cks3LLGsErmtcToNNeC85DNQw2qHZ2mCKd/E666hb7ds4w5d+m3dl2tE0Wo/JU47Laz7MbZncmE8Vlnsw1o+0nkbGzXvOOgWMT6dd9fPnhm0CaLSZl6Eld9htuMxMOjna8AsjL9WSt6SydhhHEv14K7bekjUpPEtnROS1I8nSlrOsR2Y3RN5vB4BIslTnjbJFZY5rzugg8z4KbbejuU9ttFgfcrxOe18zWljd5wJ5DxWJmVoSVzYbajMQOhdrwCbZ9E3rHjLc0TRacGVoWnBsFqN5J0AB6rOyeKVz2xvDiw6OA6FJiY5hYvWeJZCxp5gH3KQAOS1I8lTktGsyzG6ZvNgPFG5Ok+y6s2zGZm82A8VdtvSdyntt6ItD6axvadn6ZFvjmNVlnuRRQh4kZq8axgnvJtt6O5SYzEtpNNVz25avFUhmuTRQmQcBvcFlnydKs1jprMbBJ3STzTbb0ncpjlt6JotSxkqdVrDPZjjD+7qeaxZW0+DGPsV3jUaEOHFIrM4WdSsRM54dBFxauWEmbkpvnboI2kN8+qXM1A61BBUtMe8yhsjWnU6LXbtnDn36Yzn+HaROiLm7pREQEREBERAREQEREBQpUIKbmxK7aKUObVc3sBuekngB10UUYIorFGLKPifCIXGIk6s118/JWe7jKWQ3fSq7Jdw8N4clNnGU7ldsE9dj42d1pHL2L1Rrxtir509Jbfa33/amhsEu8K08G5DZk7CKYeo8acR5Lcpupvfi5fR44GdrI0gnVod5Hw15KwuweMdWNc04+y13t3Tqsj8XSlqx1n1mGGMgtbpy0Vtr1n2zXpLxOZx9lobSbhq1xN/6xnb2vhp5+Sr+WbRdfmrU9zsX9n2jY+7rvfgrtLXinhdDLGHxuGhaeRC04cFjIBpHUjby5Dz1WdLWrSPLrr9PfUtmMeXAzdaOjYlZUYIo5K/1jWDTUAj/SwZZ2NhkhbjjGN+u4PEZ4FunDVWjJU3T15H1w0WdwtY5w14eC4ONwjrF1r7GLjpxMaQ8A69oTw+C66epG3Np4efW0bRfbWOf017zmufLvH6gxw9qR+z1WPM/R4tvhoFm5JXHaNj5cxp71bo8ZTijdGyBu65gYRpzaOiwRYDFwgiOnG3XnoFiuvWPbpbpLz48eWjFUgoZymK0YiEkJDg3rosd1tJ20MgyW5uCD6rtOXmu8a0LpmSlgL2DRrvBYrmNp5ANFqBsu6dRqOS5xqxnM+nedCduK45z/AAqWNiptsVG2g0UyZTDv90nXh9yVnUjfYGbhrR2yGE8hqOnvVtsYylarNrzV2Pib3W6cAsQwmNFc1xUjERIJbp1XXv1nnLz/AId4xEY+/H9K1N9HDG5CS0WemCVxBPeHH1dF1Mu0W8FUbLxEro97z10XRnwmNsyiWapG94GmpHRbL6sL4mROjBYwgtHhpyWJ1a5iYy6V6e0RaJx5jH7+Va2iqMqehR1oIGRGT1g8aMJ04arRbXeyB77Dq4qSWG9o2A6tHirnaqQXITDYibJGejgsceNpxVDUZXYITzZpwKtdfFYiUv0kzebRx9/TgZJmKb2Ig7IVzO30jc7vlqsFivBJZvHGhu5Exsnqd0PHgrHFiMfDVfVZVjEL+83TmslXH1KUBhrwtjjPMAc1I1oiPGVnprWnziP6U62+a9jZMlut3bEzWkSct0ePlqvD6ckjJi/0URPcxr2Vzw5q6+g1hVNXsW9iRpuacFjhxFCvB2EVZjY97e0Hitx1ERGIhznorTOZn/rl5mlBjsdHbqQNjdWcH+oOYC2cDEfot1iTUOskyH38lnzMM1jHOggbq6Qhp8h1W5BE2GBkQHBjQFxm+dPE85eiuljWmY4x+1Ki7KtbDGtgsh8juzlYd2RrvMdVgpQWLDK+4accgkJ3tT2pOvHVXSPE0IrZtsrMbM7m8DijMRQjtutMrMEzub9OK7/k19PN+FeZ5cnCYmnJi3yOgY6WVz9XkceZWhSMtp8kEoOmPic3j1PT7lbYYIq8fZxNDWjjoF5bTrtMhbGAZe//ADLl3vMzLvPS/wCNYj45/n7KqY9tF9ln0lubgrDsxJy81r3mtOUkbA2oYOwAi7c8A3yVsnw9CzFHFNWY9sfcBHJLGIoW2xtnqseIu4COS3GvWJz5crdJea7fCpy1TXirvklqzyNhOsMp4Fn8pXZsPifsm18TDHGWAhpOunFdSziaFxsbbFZjxH3dRyWaWpBNWNZ8YMRGm700Wba0Wxn23TprU3Y+YVqx2bb1tzAwSuqgsPU8OOixshxb34k0hGZw4F27z89VZDjKZkiea7d6EaMOnIKK2KoVJ3TwVmMkfzcAr3ox8p+LbPx98t3oiIvK+glERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQQpREEIpRBCKUQFClEBQpRAUKUQFClEBERAREQEREBERBCKUQQpREEKURBClEQQpREBERAREQEREH//Z';
    doc.addImage( imgData, 'JPEG', 63, 20, 79, 34 );
    doc.setFontSize(11);
    doc.text(25, 60, 'Please print off and include this form with your device shipment. This will enable us to process');
    doc.text(40, 65, 'your case without delay. You will be contacted as soon as your device arrives!');
    doc.setFontSize(14);
    doc.setFontType("bold");
    doc.text(63, 79, 'HARD DRIVE SUBMISSION FORM');
    doc.setFontSize(11);
    var body_offset = 93;
    var current_height = 93;
    var line = 8;
    var left = 22;
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName( "fieldscontact" );
    var pdfcont=btoa(doc2.output('dataurlnewwindow'));
```

Comment: what do you mean by *"print out box will also open"* ?

Comment: yes this is what i mean. @Fred-ii-
please help me.. i am in big trouble

Comment: I asked you a "question" lol I don't understand what you mean by *"print out box will also open"* be more precise.

Comment: I mean to say.. when someone download a pdf file.. print dialog automatically pop up... like user dont need to click on print button, it will automatically in front of him when he opens the pdf.. did you got me?

Comment: you can't control that, in order to automatically "print" a document as that is an OS security issue. You can however invoke a JS method such as `window.print();` if that's what the question's about.

Comment: i cant invoke js method, because user first download the file and than open it.. i have seen it working and client show me and he wanst teh same

Comment: why can't you invoke JS? that's what your code is.

Comment: dear, windows.print() cant add functionality in pdf file.. its just open in browser not when file is downloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added a line of code and include the file and its start working..

```
doc.printout();
```

The about function allow me to open a popup for print.